# copy without overwrite and preserve existing files with extended name

Tags: perl, unix

i need to copy files with specific extensions. but the problem is there are multiple files with same file name.i dont want to overwrite them and store as copy like file _1,file_2 etc. when i tried using unix command line the files are overwitten though i used cp -n.
is there any way i can do this task using command line or perl ?
the command i used was

> find -L . -name "*.txt" -exec cp -n {} -t ~/destination

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also use the `cp --backup=numbered` option.

Answer (score 1):

In Perl (untested)

```
perl -MFile::Copy=cp -e '-e ($n = "~/destination/$_") or cp $_, $n for @ARGV' *.txt
```

Answer (score -1):

The below perl script recursively finding the files and copying into the destination folders however if already exists it will rename the file as filename_1, filename_2

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Find;
use File::Spec::Functions qw'catfile';
use File::Copy qw'move';
#use autodie    qw'move';
use File::Basename;

my ($filename);#    = 'DUMBFILE';
my $origin      = '/home/itadmin/FoldersFind/OriginalFolder';
my $destination = '/home/itadmin/FoldersFind/Destination';

mkdir($destination, 0777); 
my ($path);
find(\&wanted, $origin);

sub wanted
{
    if(-e $origin)
    {
        if($File::Find::name=~m/\.(txt|html|xml)$/gs)
        {
            $filename = basename($File::Find::name);
        }
    }
    $path = "$destination/$filename";
    my $cnt;
    while(-e $path)
    {
        $cnt++;
        $path = catfile $destination, "$filename.$cnt";
    }
    move($filename, $path);
}
```

Input: (Fetching files may be duplicate)

```
/OriginalFolder/<folders1>/*file
/OriginalFolder/<folders2>/*file
```

Output: (Renaming)

```
/Destination/*file_<count> #/Destination/*file_1
/Destination/*file_<count> #/Destination/*file_2
```